# Adjust edge length with Geometry Nodes relative to center

Tags: geometry-nodes

I was following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llJdazdLmBU) and it was great!

But I would like to modify it little. When I find the corner vertex, is it possible add new vertices at a certain (constant) distance in the same direction of the edges and connect them to the center vertex?

Maybe the pictures explain it better...

This is the beginning:

[image]

And this is the result I want:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To move the endpoints of a mesh line with equal distance to its center, you can use the following setup:

[image]

You won't get around a little vector math here, but it's simpler than it looks:

1. First subtract or add to the index of the start and end points $1$. this will allow you to query the position of the next or previous index respectively.
2. Then subtract this position from the position of the respective point, normalize the vector and scale it with the desired value.
3. Last, add this vector to the position of the center point to get the positions of the endpoints you are looking for.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: This almost works, but the problem is that the start might be uneven. I mean that other edge might be longer than the other, so the trim would also be uneven

Comment: @Härkäniemi Ah, sorry, it may be that I misunderstood the question! You want a uniform distance FROM the center away!? ...all clear! ...the answer has been edited accordingly.